# update form Validation angular 2 using formbuilder

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I've been trying to work on Angular 2 forms  using formBuilder .
My form component has  2 form groups :

```
    constructor(fb: FormBuilder){
            let self = this;
            this.myForm= fb.group({
            primaryAddress : fb.group({
               landMark : [this.landMarks],
               home : fb.group({
                address : ['',Validators.required],
                geoCord : ['',Validators.required],
               }),
            }),
        });
```

I'm emiting Geocords from mapComponent whenever places are changed:

```
this.addressMarker.addListener('dragend', () => {
        this.changedGeocode = (this.addressMarker.getPosition().lat()).toFixed(6) + "," + (this.addressMarker.getPosition().lng()).toFixed(6);
        this.emitGeoCode.emit(this.changedGeocode);
    });
```

i listen to this event in my formcomponent like this:

```
geoCodeChanged(event){
        let geocode=this.myForm.get('primaryAddress.home.geoCord');
        geocode.patchValue(event);
}
```

The problem i'm facing is that the validators of geocord is not changing from ng-invalid to ng-valid after geoCodeChanged(event) has occured .

formcomponent template :

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)" style="position: relative;width: 100%;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="left:0%;position: relative;margin-bottom: 20px;"(click)="resetForm()">Reset</button>
    <div formGroupName=primaryAddress>
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
            <label for="landmark">LandMark:</label>
            <select id="landmark" class="form-control" style="width:80%;" formControlName="landMark">
                <option *ngFor="let landmark of landMarks" [value]="landmark.id">{{landmark.address}}</option>
            </select>{{landmark}}
        </div>
            <div formGroupName=home>
                <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
                        <label for="home">Home:</label>
                        <textarea id="home" type="text" size="35" rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" style="width:80%;" formControlName="address">{{home}}</textarea>
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
                        <label for="geocodeInput">GeoCode:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="geocodeInput" class="form-control" style="width:60%;" placeholder="GeoCode" formControlName = "geoCord">
                        <span id="search" style="color: blue" (click)="searchMap()">(Search using Map)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="left: 50%;" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I've tried setValue() , updateValueAndValidity(). No change to ng-invalid
What am i missing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use this.applicationRef.tick();

Comment: @YoavSchniederman i used `this.applicationRef.tick()` . Application threw an error stating `ApplicationRef.tick is called recursively` . I looked what it actually does , and ended up calling `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` , and it worked . Thank you for the reply  : )